# Android MediaPlayer Prepare

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play mp3 file using Android MediaPlayer API as following ,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFYMq.png)

but unfortunately prepare() method dosn't work with the following error:

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
>               at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
>               at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1282)
>               at com.baraka.activity.HfzHome.onCreate(HfzHome.java:47)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>       09-11 02:17:38.560 24146-24146/com.baraka W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>               at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>               at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>               at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>       09-11 02:17:38.561 24146-24146/com.baraka W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: try removing call `mediaPlayer.reset()` before `mediaPlayer.prepare()`

Comment: thx, but it was becuase of sdk 28 so i downgraded it to 27 and it works fine. thx again

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mediaplayer.reset()`

> There is a subtle but important difference between a newly constructed
>   MediaPlayer object and the MediaPlayer object after reset() is called.
>   It is a programming error to invoke methods such as
>   getCurrentPosition(), getDuration(), getVideoHeight(),
>   getVideoWidth(), setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes),
>   setLooping(boolean), setVolume(float, float), pause(), start(),
>   stop(), seekTo(long, int), prepare() or prepareAsync() in the Idle
>   state for both cases. If any of these methods is called right after a
>   MediaPlayer object is constructed, the user supplied callback method
>   OnErrorListener.onError() won't be called by the internal player
>   engine and the object state remains unchanged; but if these methods
>   are called right after reset(), the user supplied callback method
>   OnErrorListener.onError() will be invoked by the internal player
>   engine and the object will be transfered to the Error state.

Start out something simple like this to get it work before you started to mess with other functionalities:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    String website = "website url here";//put ur url here
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(website);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
}
```

A good, old [tutorial](https://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class) might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of invistifation, i found that problem was in the SdkVersion i downraded it from 
compileSdkVersion 28 into compileSdkVersion 27, then it works fine. thx for your answers.